# deserialize json to object c# on windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm trying to deserialize json data services recieved from a web server into an object. So far i have just set up a httpwebrequest which gets json fromatted data from the server.

```
public void DoHttpWebRequest(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(onGetResponse), request);
}

public void onGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

    using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBlock5.Text = results);
    }
    myResponse.Close();
}
```

This returns the following data.

```
{"BodyStyle":"Sports","ChassisNumber":19316,"Colour":"Ivory","Condition":"Showroom","Model":"Silver Wraith","Owners":[{"DateBought":"\/Date(-207269643940+0100)\/","DateSold":"\/Date(-113297981580+0100)\/","ID":651,"Owner":{"Address":null,"Decorations":null,"Email":"jvcuejnj.ldmfkiftvh@wx-sts.net","Forename":"Ismael","ID":637,"Mobile":"008547-4461","Surname":"Anderson","Telephone":"366892-9004","Title":"Mr"}}],"RegistrationNumber":"RB4107  ","Year":1909}
```

how can I use DataContractJsonSerializer to parse the data into an object with the classes below?

```
public class CarOwnershipRecord { 
    public int? ID{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateBought{ get; set; } 
    public DateTime? DateSold{ get; set; } 
    public Person Owner{ get; set; } 
} 

public class Car { 
    public string BodyStyle{ get; set; } 
    public short? ChassisNumber{ get; set; } 
    public string Colour{ get; set; } 
    public string Condition{ get; set; } 
    public string Model{ get; set; }
    public List<CarOwnershipRecord> Owners{ get; set; } 
    public string RegistrationNumber{ get; set; } 
    public short Year{ get; set; } 
}

public class CarPhoto {
    public string RegistrationNumber{ get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo{ get; set; }
    // The Photo field contains the binary contents of an image file
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should give you the right result:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(data);
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Car));
Car car = (Car) serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
```

Although you could just deserialize directly from the response stream if you want to skip the MemoryStream part

Comment: Thanks this is what i'm looking for. However in my json data i have the main object and then another array of objects which is defined as `public List<CarOwnershipRecord> Owners{ get; set; }`. How would you go about deserialising this data within the same json stream?

Comment: As long as you have all your DTOs (Car, CarOwnerShipRecord and Person) mapped out right, the serializer should take care of everything for you with just the single call to ReadObject()

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: http://json.codeplex.com/